# Как можно релизовать указание на HTML странице на различие в тексте

Tags: javascript, html

Проверяются формулы на правильность ввода. Нужно под формулами указать символом ^ позиции где есть некорректный ввод.

```
(a+b) - (a-b)

(a+b - (a-b
    ^      ^
```

Comment: Вопрос про синтаксический анализ? Формулы – только 4 оператора и скобки, или что-то ещё?

Comment: Да только эти операторы и скобки.

Comment: Задача как формулируется:  даны две строки с формулами, и нужно для второй показать места различий с первой?

Comment: Формула считается неправильной если в ней имеются открывающие скобки, для которых нет закрывающих или наоборот, если есть закрывающие, для которых нет открывающих. Строкой ниже символом "^" указать позиции неправильных скобок, для которых нет пары.

Comment: Позиции можно определить множеством вариантов. В примере выше можно закрыть и так: `(a)+b - (a)-b`. Где должна быть закрывающая скобка в формуле `(a + b - a - b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто проверяем количество открытых и закрытых скобок. Если количества не совпадают, то где-то ошибка. Но функция находит только одну ошибку.

Функцию отображения ошибки возьмите у @Sergiks

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var value = this.value;
  var opened = 0;
  var last = 0;
  
  for(var i=0, sp=value.split(""); i < sp.length; i++) {
    if(sp[i] == "(") {
      last = i;
      opened++;
    }
    
    if(sp[i] == ")"){
      last = i;
      opened--;
    }
    
    if(opened < 0) {
       show_error(last);
       break;
    }
  }
  
  if(opened != 0) {
    show_error(last);
  }
  
});

function show_error(sym_no) {
  alert(sym_no);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input>
```

Comment: Наверное, тут надо минимально токенизировать строку, чтобы проверять на ошибки вроде `(a b)`, `a - () b`, `a b + - ()`

Comment: @Sergiks а у тс [говорится](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539326/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5/539431?noredirect=1#comment680617_539326) только о скобках

Answer (score 1):

Что касается размещения указателей под строкой – легко решается относительным/абсолютным позиционированием. В строке перед нужным местом вставляется `<span>^</span>` и сдвигается вниз на высоту строки.

Допустим, вы как-то узнали, что ошибки находятся на позициях 14 и 6 (порядок не важен):

```js
placeMarks(14,6);

function placeMarks() {
  var el = document.getElementById("code")
    ,html = el.innerText.trim()
    ,insert = '<span class="here">^</span>'
    ,places = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).sort((a,b)=>a-b)
    ,pieces = []
    ,i
    ,j = 0
  ;
  for(i=0; i<places.length;i++) {
    pieces.push( html.slice(j,places[i]));
    j = places[i];
  }
  pieces.push( html.slice(j));
  el.innerHTML = pieces.join(insert);
}
```

```css
#code {font-size:16px;font-family:Courier New, monospace;position:relative}
.here {
  position:absolute;
  top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="code">a+b+c ) * (a-b /(a-c)</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Нужно добавить элемент содержащий ^ с абсолютной позицией и установить его в некие координаты. Вопрос так поникаю - как эти координаты вычислить.

Решение есть шаманское: создаём 2 span-а со шрифтом аналогичным тому куда у тебя формулы пишутся. 
В 1й span мы добавляем по символу через <BR> - столько же, на какой строке у тебя находится место на которое надо указать. 
Во 2й span мы добавляем последнюю строку до символа - на который требуется указать. А затем получаес координаты так:

```
var coordinates = {
 x: span2.offsetWidth,
 y: span1.offsetHeight
};
```

Другого способа определения координат символа не видел.